# **Long** type in protobuf compiled js

Tags: javascript, typescript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I updated my `protobufjs` to version `7.1.0` then the `Long` type in it got different from my `Long` type and it said you should import it from `protobufjs` but after that the error still been.

The `Long` type in compiled protobuf refers to a class but imported `Long` refers to a type!

What can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It need to install `Long` package I tried that and the problem fixed